# Inequality string for comparison of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, factorial

I'd like to know if the following statement is a valid one. Specifically, I hope to use it in applying comparison tests for convergence/divergence of certain series.

*For sufficiently large n,*

$n, n^2, n^3, n^4, ... < 2^n, 3^n, 4^n, ... < n!$

The statement wasn't in my text, and I couldn't find it anywhere -- but I tried to recall it from back when I took Calculus II myself.

Is the above statement correct ? Further, can the above statement be expanded upon to say

*For sufficiently large n*,

$n^c < a^n < n!$ ,

where $c$ is any positive real number and $a$ is any real number greater than $1$ ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proofs are relatively easy.

$n^c \lt a^n$ can be gotten by taking log.  $clog(n)\lt nlog(a)$ or $\frac{c}{log(a)}\lt \frac{n}{log(n)}$ for large enough $n$.

Using Stirling formila $n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$ allows  $a^n\lt n!$  to be  $1\lt \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{ae})^n$, as long as $n\ge ae$.

The expansion is more general (as I interpret it)  The first inequality looks like $n^k\lt k^n$ for fixed $k$ and large $n$.